# Using AWS Educate with Spring

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am using an AWS Educate account and I would like to use S3 in my Java Spring Boot application.

I try to create a bucket using the following code where in place of access key and secret key I use those listed in Account Details from vocareum page:

```
@Repository
public class S3Repository {
    
    private final AmazonS3 s3Client;
    
    public S3Repository() {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                "<AWS accesskey>",
                "<AWS secretkey>"
        );
        this.s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                                             .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                                             .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                                             .build();
    }
    
    public void createBucket(String name) {
        s3Client.createBucket(name);
    }

}
```

When I invoke `createBucket(String name)` get this exception:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

I tried creating a new user in IAM but it does not create an access key and secret key due to educating account limitations. Every time I sign in to aws educate account it generates new keys and I'm using current ones. Configuration with YAML file and auto wiring s3Client gives the same result.

Is there any additional configuration that I need to include?

I would like to avoid creating a new regular account if there is another solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you may already know, AWS Educate account have limitation across many services.

AWS Educate account's credential (access key, secret key, session token) would always change within 2-3 hours. But you can use this information to implement what you want.

All you need to do is add a session token along with an access key and secret key. Here is the sample code:

```
BasicSessionCredentials sessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
            "<type your aws_access_key_id>",
            "<type your aws_secret_access_key>",
            "<type your aws_session_token>");

final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(sessionCredentials)).withRegion(
            Regions.US_EAST_1).build();

// do whatever you want with s3
...
```

Please note that this program would work for few hours while the credentials are valid. However, when the session expires, you would get the error again. This is the limitation of the AWS educate account.

src: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html